# How to use link table with Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

In my Laravel 4 app, I have two models: Country and Grade wrote them as:

Country.php:

```
class Country extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function grades()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Grade', 'title');
    }
}
```

Grade.php:

```
class Grade extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function country()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo('Country');
    }
}
```

when I try to get all grades for specific country:

```
return Response::json(Country::find($country_id)->grades());
```

But this would result into empty object `{}`

I am using many to many link table:

```
Schema::create('countries_grades', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('country_id');
            $table->integer('grade_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

It seems that laravel is not using the above table, what is the correct way to achieve this query?

**EDIT**

Thanks for answers below! but I have found that no mater what I do, I will get empty object if I called graded as a method:

```
return Response::json(Country::find($country_id)->grades());
```

this should be:

```
return Response::json(Country::find($country_id)->grades);
```

otherwise, it woks well if I use `belongsToMany` for both `Grade` and `Country`

I hope this will help others!

Comment: just to get a clear picture, are your trying to specify a many-to-many relation? one course has many grades, and one grade has many courses?

Comment: one country has many grades, grade belongs to one country

Comment: then you don't need a many-to-many relationship, the pivot table `countries_grades ` is not needed. I will update my answer with what you need.

Comment: sure :) but, my reputation is less that 15 :( I can't vote up, but only accept the answer, do you think many-to-many is slower that belongsTo ?

Comment: That means, after setting a relationship in a model, invoking as function takes to the table, and as an attribute takes to the items, aha?

Comment: invoking as function return empty object, but I don't know why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your Schema you are trying to define a Many-To-Many query, the proper way of doing this is returning the call to the method `belongsToMany()`. Example:

```
class Country extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function grades()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Grade', 'countries_grades');
    }
}
```

and...

```
class Grade extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function country()
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany('Country', 'countries_grades');
    }
}
```

### UPDATE One-To-many Relationship

If what you want to achieve is a one country have many grades and one grade belongs to one country, you have to do the following.

Add an integer field called `country_id` in the `grades` table, and then add the following relationships to you classes:

```
class Country extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function grades()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Grade');
    }
}
```

and...

```
class Grade extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function country()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo('Country');
    }
}
```

Then after this, one country can access the grades like this:

```
$country = Country::find(1);
$country->grades;
```

and to get the country that a grade belongs to you could do it in this way:

```
$grade = Grade::find(1);
$grade->country;
```

Comment: This would be ok on small ammounts of related entities, for speed reasons the keys should be defined explicitly too, see my answer below ;)

Comment: @VitKos sounds reasonable, then the framework has to do less calculations :)

Comment: @AmjadEmerah you're right, speed had me write that typo there

Comment: one country has many grades, grade belongs to one country, do I have the correct design?

Comment: @AmjadEmerah no, right now you have an architecture that supports one country have many grades and one grade have many countries. I'll update my answer with the right code to have one course have many grade, and one grade belongs to a course.

Comment: @AmjadEmerah I updated the answer, please read after the Update One-To-Many relationship